# Get updates only one time per message

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Im building a Telegram bot using the official API and python with the requests lib

I`ve add a command named text, that return "example text" when it is called. Until here all ok, but the bot only send a response when the python script is executed

So I do that the script execute indefinitely with a white True condition.

The problem is that if I execute indefinitely the script it will be making requests all the time to the API, so if I check the last message all the time with the script, the last message will be /text until I write another message.

How can do that the function that read the command will execute only one time when a new command will requested?

The code is the next:

```py
# TELEGRAM BOT USING THE API

import requests as req
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pprint import pprint
import re
import os

config = load_dotenv(".env")

teletoken = os.environ.get("telegram_token")

uri = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{teletoken}/"

# Dynamic Telegram API method
def method(method):
    return f"{uri}{method}"

# Response to a command
def get_and_response(chat_id: str or int):
    updates = req.get(method("getUpdates"))
    response = updates.json()
    command_regex = re.findall("^/text*", response["result"][-1]["message"]["text"])
    if command_regex == ["/text"]:
        req.post(method("sendMessage"), data={"chat_id": chat_id, "text": "Example text"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        get_and_response(*chat_id*)
```

Comment: You are using the polling functionality. You can either add a Delay/sleep. Or try to use the webhook: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook

Comment: ok, I will try with webhooks so, thanks @GeorgeBakaev